# Updating Redux with Sqlite3 in an Electron application

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, redux, electron

I am writing an Electron application and I want to display some data from a local sqlite3 database file. I am using React as my front-end framework and Redux to update the table data. However I am having trouble figuring out what's the best way to query from the .db file and update Redux with the new data. Can someone give me some insights on what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Maybe check out this library. http://knexjs.org/ I think you will find it very useful.

Comment: Currently I'm using the sqlite3 node module in my renderer.js file to read from the .db file. I am also able to send those data to main.js, however, I have trouble updating redux with main.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to load a .db file using the node module sqlite3 and included a javascript function as such:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let dbSrc = 'processlist.db';

var fetchDBData = (tablename) => {
  var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbSrc);
  var queries = [];
    db.each("SELECT * FROM " + tablename, function(err, row) {
        queries.push(row);
    });


    db.close();
    return queries;
};
```

Since I am using React and Redux for my front end, I was able to invoke this function by calling

```
window.fetchDBData(tablename);
```